# How can i make a Link input Field in TCA

Tags: typo3-tca

I need the same function like the TYPO3 standard. There you can choose a link (external Site, internal Site, File, etc.)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find the TCA for the TYPO3 backend in the files typo3/sysext/cms/tbl_tt_content.php and typo3/sysext/cms/tbl_cms.php.
Here you find the header_link example.

**Solution for TYPO3 6.1 and lower:**

```
'header_link' => array(
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:header_link',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => '50',
        'max' => '256',
        'eval' => 'trim',
        'wizards' => array(
            '_PADDING' => 2,
            'link' => array(
                'type' => 'popup',
                'title' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:header_link_formlabel',
                'icon' => 'link_popup.gif',
                'script' => 'browse_links.php?mode=wizard',
                'JSopenParams' => 'height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
            ),
        ),
        'softref' => 'typolink',
    ),
),
```

**Solution for TYPO3 6.2.x - 7.6.x:**

```
'header_link' => array(
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:header_link',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => '50',
        'max' => '256',
        'eval' => 'trim',
        'wizards' => array(
            '_PADDING' => 2,
            'link' => array(
                'type' => 'popup',
                'title' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:header_link_formlabel',
                'icon' => 'EXT:backend/Resources/Public/Images/FormFieldWizard/wizard_link.gif',
                'module' => array(
                    'name' => 'wizard_element_browser',
                    'urlParameters' => array(
                        'mode' => 'wizard',
                        'act' => 'page'
                    )
                ),
                'JSopenParams' => 'height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
            ),
        ),
        'softref' => 'typolink',
    ),
),
```

**Solution for TYPO3 8.x:**

```
'header_link' => array(
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:header_link',
    'exclude' => 1,
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'renderType' => 'inputLink',
    ),
),
```

Comment: The important part is the ``wizards`` configuration.

Comment: You can use blindLinkOptions so restrict the user to particular output. You can check here. http://snipplr.com/view/71972/allow-only-certain-link-types-in-typo3-link-wizard/

Comment: This is outdated and made lot simpler in newer TYPO3 versions via `renderType`.

Comment: there is a missing bracket `),` in version 8.x can't change since editing restrictions are min 6 chars)

Comment: type='input' with renderType='inputLink' is deprecated since version v12, should use type='link' then, see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input/Index.html and https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Link/Index.html#columns-link

Answer (score 7):

Since TYPO3 8.x, use type='input' with  [`'renderType' => 'inputLink'`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input/Link/Examples.html#link-field) to your `input` field:

```
'columns' => [
    'a_link_field' => [
        'label' => 'Link',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'renderType' => 'inputLink',
        ],
    ],
]
```

Comment: type="intput" with renderType="inputLink" has been deprecated since version 12.0, use Link instead: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Link/Index.html#columns-link

Answer (score 6):

The TCA looks slightly different in the new version 7 of TYPO3:

```
        'link' => array(
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:header_link',
            'exclude' => 1,
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => '50',
                'max' => '1024',
                'eval' => 'trim',
                'wizards' => array(
                    'link' => array(
                        'type' => 'popup',
                        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:header_link_formlabel',
                        'icon' => 'link_popup.gif',
                        'module' => array(
                            'name' => 'wizard_element_browser',
                            'urlParameters' => array(
                                'mode' => 'wizard'
                            )
                        ),
                        'JSopenParams' => 'height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1'
                    )
                ),
                'softref' => 'typolink'
            )
        ),
```

Comment: Thanx for keeping this topic alive with an uptodate answer. Another small change for the edit icon to be displayed correctly in Typo3 >= 7.5: `'icon' => 'EXT:backend/Resources/Public/Images/FormFieldWizard/wizard_link.gif'`.

Answer (score 4):

Following will work for TYPO3 7.6.X

```
'detailpage' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myExt_domain_model_mdl1.detailpage',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim',
                'wizards' => array(
                    '_PADDING' => 2,
                    'link' => array(
                        'type' => 'popup',
                        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:header_link_formlabel',
                        'icon' => 'link_popup.gif',
                        'module' => array(
                            'name' => 'wizard_element_browser',
                            'urlParameters' => array(
                                'mode' => 'wizard',
                                'act' => 'page'
                            )
                        ),
                        'JSopenParams' => 'height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
                    ),
                ),
                'softref' => 'typolink',
            ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since TYPO3 v12, use [type='link'](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Link/Index.html#columns-link):

```
'a_link_field' => [
    'label' => 'Link',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'link',
        'allowedTypes' => ['page', 'url', 'record'],
    ]
]
```

Before TYPO3 v12 (and since TYPO3 8.x), use type='input' with  [`'renderType' => 'inputLink'`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input/Link/Examples.html#link-field) to your `input` field:

```
'a_link_field' => [
    'label' => 'Link',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'input',
        'renderType' => 'inputLink',
        'fieldControl' => [
            'linkPopup' => [
                'options' => [
                    // Comma separated list of link options that should not be displayed. 
                    // Possible values are file, folder, mail, page, telephone and url. 
                    // By default, all link options are displayed. 
                    'blindLinkOptions' => 'folder,mail,telephone,page',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

*Code snippets from the documentation, slightly modfied.*

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Link/Index.html#columns-link
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input/Properties/LinkPopup.html#tca-field-control-link-popup